# TouchDown Event UIbutton to record Audio not triggered, due to Collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, audio, uibutton, audio-recording

I'm using [JSQMessagesViewController](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController) to implement a chat. I added a record button and want to send Audio Messages by holding that button down to record and stop recording by releasing the button. 
Currently I'm trying to do it this way:

```
record_button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
    record_button.tintColor = UIColor.white
    record_button.setImage(recordImage, for: .normal)

    self.recordingSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do {
        try self.recordingSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try self.recordingSession.setActive(true)
        self.recordingSession.requestRecordPermission() { [unowned self] allowed in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if allowed {
                    self.record_button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ChatViewController.recording), for: .touchDown )
                    self.record_button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ChatViewController.recordTapRelease), for: .touchUpInside)
                    self.record_button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ChatViewController.recordTapRelease), for: .touchDragExit)
                } else {
                    // failed to record!
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        // failed to record!
    }
```

Unfortunately it does not work correctly. It only works when I press the button move up the touch. Only then it recognises the hold event and records. When I touch and hold at the same location it does not record, and when I release the touch it sends an Audio Message of 1 second.

**EDIT**
*I realised that the problem is my Collectionview which has a ScrollView. The scrollview delays the touchdown event in order to check whether the user scrolls. How am I supposed to trigger the touchdown event anyway?*

[image: ChatViewController]

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use Gesture recognizers instead.

```
let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longTouched))
button.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)

func longTouched(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .began {
      //triggered after long pressed
    }else if gesture.state == .ended || gesture.state == .cancelled {
      //end of the touch
    }
}
```

If you need to detect the beginning of the touch, you can also add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the button.
in which case you might want to:

```
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
```

Comment: Tried this before and did not have any success with it.

Comment: Well, I did like that in my project and it works :) can't open the full sources though.

Comment: The problem for me is the scrollView Controller. Check my edit.

Comment: If your bottom bar is not within the collectionView items list, it should work. I would create a UIView for the bottom bar and add it to the Controller.view